# Magento 2 | i see a different customer name when i login

Tags: magento2, customer, session, customer-session

When I try to log in from the homepage of my site I see a name different from mine.

For example, instead of seeing the name John Doe I see the name Jackson appear which is not my name.

This problem is solved as soon as I clear the cache but I cannot clear the cache every time I log in.

This appears to be a session refresh issue or cache issue...
Has anyone had this problem and know how to fix it?

My Magento version is 2.4.2 with Varnish cache enabled.

Thanks

Comment: In your custom code or mangeto code?

Comment: In frontend of My Magento website